# redux reducer... + 1 I have created a new array and added one. now how do I put it back together and return the new state

Tags: javascript, arrays, redux

This almost works but its not updating the ui....
so found the index of what I want to change, I created a new array newFavorites and increased a value on one of its keys (sets +1).  But I am not sure how to return the new state with the updated key value.

here is the model.  i just want to add one to the sets

```
class Exercise {
    constructor(id, name, gifUrl, equipment, sets=4){
        this.id = id;
        this.name = name;
        this.gifUrl = gifUrl;
        this.equipment = equipment;
        this.sets = sets;

    }
}

export default Exercise;


    const initialState = {
        favoritedExercises: [],
    
    }
            case ADD_SETS: 
           const index= state.favoritedExercises.findIndex(fav => fav.id === action.payload.id);
           let newFavorites = [...state.favoritedExercises];
            newFavorites[index].sets + 1;
          
            
           
           
          return {
              ...state,
            favoritedExercises: newFavorites
          }
```

Comment: Please revise your post title to ask a clear, specific question in one complete sentence. See [ask].

Answer (score 0):

for anyone else who might have this missunderstandiing..

```
case ADD_SETS: 
               const index= state.favoritedExercises.findIndex(fav => fav.id === action.payload.id);
               let newFavorites = [...state.favoritedExercises];
                newFavorites[index].sets = newFavorites[index].sets + 1;
                console.log(newFavorites[index])
              
            
           
           
          return {
              ...state,
            favoritedExercises: newFavorites
          }
```

Comment: Some explanation of your solution would make this a better answer. Please see [answer].